# Dejar elemento Html fijo en pantalla

Tags: css, css3

Buen día.

Quisiera que me puedan dar una mano, estoy intentando dejar un nav fijo en la parte superior de la pantalla. Yo sé que eso se puede lograr con position: fixed;

Pero el detalle es que ese nav está debajo de un encabezado. Quisiera que el navbar se quede fijo al momento de que baje la pantalla y desaparezca el título de arriba.

Espero me entiendan y puedan ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es mi página, quisiera que el navbar que está debajo del título quede fijo en la parte superior al bajar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Deberías publicar el código de lo que has intentado hacer para que podamos ayudarte. De todos modos, hecha un vistazo a este link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp

Comment: @andyio Muchas gracias por tu comentarios, creo que con el link es suficiente muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Tomaré en cuenta lo de subir mi código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para estos casos, o se hace via JS o con la propiedad display: sticky.

```
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Puedes ver más información aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sirvió, quería buscarlo en internet pero no sabía como encontrarlo. Muchas gracias por el apoyo.